# Ramification of primes in cyclotomic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I don't know a lot of algebraic number theory, but I think the following is true: let $E/\mathbf{Q}$ be an algebraic number field, and $p\in\mathbf{Z}$ a prime. Then there a unique integers $e,f,g$ depending only on $p$ and $E$, such that (a) there are exactly $g$ distinct prime ideals occuring the factorization of $p\mathcal{O}_E$, each with multiplicity $e$, and (b) the dimension of the residue field is $f$.

Now I wonder whether for $E=\mathbf{Q}(\mu_n)$ (cyclotomic field) these $e,f,g$ can be given explicitly for a given prime $p$? I mean is there a formula for these quantities? I know that these are related by $efg=\phi(n)$, but this alone does not suffice.

Comment: There is a strong relation between these quantities and subgroups of Dirichlet characters. If this is what you're looking for, let me know and I can type it up.

Comment: @Prospect please, you would be very welcome.

Comment: I believe $E$ has to be Galois over $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Proposition 10.3 in Neukirch - Algebraic Number Theory: Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

> **(10.3) Proposition** Let $n=\displaystyle\prod_{p} p^{\nu_p}$ be the prime factorization of $n$ and, for every prime number $p$, let $f_p$ be the smallest positive integer such that $$p^{f_p}\equiv 1\pmod{n/p^{\nu_p}}.$$ Then one has in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ the factorization $$p=(\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_r)^{\varphi(p^{\nu_p})},$$ where $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots ,\mathfrak{p}_r$ are distinct prime ideals, all of degree $f_p$.