# Ramification in cyclotomic fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer and $K_m$ be the $m$-th cyclotomic field. It is well known that a prime $p$ is ramified in $K_m$ if and only it divides $m$ and in the particular case when $m=p^r$, it is totally ramified. But I do not find anything about its ramification index in the general case.

Do anyone know the ramification index of $p$ when $p\mid m$?
Thanks in advance

Comment: $m=p^n k, \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})$ is unramified at the primes  above $p$ (it is the splitting field of $x^k-1$ which is separable $\bmod p$)

Comment: It is not correct that $p$ ramifies in $K_m$ if and only if $p\mid m$. It's true that a ramified prime divides $m$, and the converse is true for odd primes, but we can have $2 \mid m$ and $2$ is unramified in $K_m$: $K_2 = \mathbf Q$ and $2$ is unramified here, and $K_{10} = K_5$ and $2$ is unramified here. The mistake you made would be similar to saying $p$ is ramified in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{n})$ if and only if $p \mid n$, which is false without specifying a definite way of describing quadratic fields (like using squarefree $n$, and still an issue occurs at $2$).

Comment: For cyclotomic fields we have duplicate labels: $K_n = K_{2n}$ for odd $n$, and that's the only way two labels describe the same cyclotomic field. So it's a standard convention to require $m$ is not twice an odd number ($m \not\equiv 2 \bmod 4$) and then it's true that $p$ ramifies in $K_m$ if and only if $p \mid m$.

Comment: Thanks kCd for this very beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $m = p^rn$ where $p \nmid n$. Then $K_m = K_{p^r}K_n$.  The prime $p$ is totally ramified in $K_{p^r}$ with ramification index $[K_{p^r}:\mathbf Q] = \varphi(p^r)$ and $p$ is unramified in $K_n$. In the composite field $K_m$, the ramification index of $p$ turns out to be the same as that in $K_{p^r}$: $\varphi(p^r)$.

Note that if $m = 2n$ and $n$ is odd, so $K_m = K_n$, $2$ is unramified in this field, so the ramification index of $2$ here is $1$ and $\varphi(2^r) = \varphi(2) = 1$. Thus my comment above about making the convention that $m \not\equiv 2 \bmod 4$ so that cyclotomic fields are listed as $K_m$ in exactly one way is actually not necessary to answer your question.

By the way, your question has been answered before on this site. Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666332/ramification-of-primes-in-cyclotomic-field).